# X11 error BadRequest when running OpenGL applications

Tags: qt, x11, opengl-es-2.0

I compiled Xorg for a custom Linux I'm building for an ARM device. I'm trying to run OpenGL applications using EGL with the Qt framework but I get these errors:

```
X Error: BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation) 1
Extension: 198 (Uknown extension)
Minor opcode: 0 (Unknown request)
Resource id: 0x600082
```

and this:

```
X Error: BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation) 1
Extension: 160 (Uknown extension)
Minor opcode: 0 (Unknown request)
Resource id: 0x600082
```

repeated many times. What does this mean? How can I investigate on what is wrong? Something is drawn on the screen correctly with OpenGL, but after that everything is screwed up.
It seems like something is missing in my Xorg, but I can't find anything about these extensions 198 and 160. How does one figure out what is missing or anyway what is wrong? Do I have to compile anything specific to be able to run OpenGL applications for X11?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension numbers are dynamically assigned by the X server based on the extensions supported in a particular codebase and enabled in a particular configuration.   To get a list of the extension name to number mappings on the current display, you can run `xdpyinfo -queryExtensions | grep opcode` — the opcode value listed for each one should match the extension number in Xlib error reports.   If none of the extensions match, then it seems likely you've got memory corruption or are calling an extension without first verifying it's currently available in the X server.

Comment: This is very useful! Thank! And is there anywhere a list of all the extensions with their opcode? So that I can try to understand what may be missing?

Comment: Please re-read the answer I gave.   There can't be a list of extensions with their opcodes, since as I said, the opcodes are *dynamically assigned*.   The Render extension could have opcode 132 on my X server, 140 on yours, depending on the order the extensions are initialized in and which ones get initialized or are disabled.

Comment: You're right, sorry. Your answer was clear. Anyway, I may have solved the problem by recompiling Qt enabling support for almost all the X extensions and then enabling multi-threading explicitly for X. It seems the application was working with the OpenGL outside the main thread. Now the problem seems solved. I don't know whether both of these actions are mandatory or not. Thanks for your help!